# How do I search a Discord user input for a value and assign it to a var?

Tags: javascript, arguments, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to search Discord User input for integers attached to attributes (Number of attacks, skill of attack, strength, toughness, save) and then run those args through some calculations.

At the moment the function uses the order of args in the command:

!odds 5 3 4 5 3

which works, but I want something like this:

!odds at: 5 sk: 3 st: 4 t: 5 sv: 3

And the bot will search the user input for values attached to those attributes in any order and use those integers for its calculations.

In addition, if attributes aren't present the bot will not include them in the output (or assign default values) and by adding additional, single phrase attributes with no attached integer (for example *fnp* or *res*) it would then add another standard calculation and output.

This is what I have so far:

```
const { Message } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'odds',
    aliases: ['stats', 'probability'],
    usage: '[#attacks (1 = auto hit)] [skill] [strength] [toughness] [save (7 = no save)]',
    description: 'What are the odds?',

    execute(message, args) {
        let attack = args[0]
        let skill;
        if (args[1]>=7) skill = 7;
        else skill = args[1];
        let strength = args[2]
        let toughness = args[3]
        let save;
        if (args[4]<=6) save = args[4];
            else save = 7;
        let hits = parseFloat((attack*((7-skill)/6)).toFixed(2))
        let hitSixes = parseFloat((attack*(1/6)).toFixed(2))
        let woundFactor; 
         if (strength>=(2*toughness)) woundFactor = 2;
        else 
        if (strength>toughness) woundFactor = 3;
        else
        if (strength==toughness) woundFactor = 4;
        else
        if (toughness>=(2*strength)) woundFactor = 6;
        else
        if (strength<toughness) woundFactor = 5;

        let wounds = parseFloat((hits*((7-woundFactor)/6)).toFixed(2))
        let woundSixes = parseFloat((hits*(1/6)).toFixed(2))
        let unsavedWounds = parseFloat(((wounds-(wounds*((7-save)/6))).toFixed(2)))

    message.channel.send(`On average you will make:\n${hits} successful hits (with ${hitSixes} sixes)\n${wounds} successful wounds (with ${woundSixes} sixes)\nGiving a total of ${unsavedWounds} unsaved wounds.`)
    }}
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
// what you accept:
const inputs = {
    at: 0,
    sk: 0,
    st: 0,
    t: 0,
    sv: 0,
}

for (let i = 0, arg; arg = args[i]; i++) {
    const index = arg.indexOf(':'); // it must have an ":" as last character
    if (index === -1) {
        continue;
    }
    const keyword = arg.substr(0, index - 1); // get the word
    if (!inputs.hasOwnProperty(keyword)) { // check if it's an element of inputs
        continue;
    }
    if (i + 1 === args.length) { // make sure enough args are available
        continue;
    }
    inputs[keyword] = isNaN(args[i + 1]) ? 0 : +args[i + 1]; // make sure it's a number
    i++; // skip the next element
}

let attack = inputs.at;
let skill = inputs.sk >= 7 ? 7 : inputs.sk;
let strength = inputs.st;
let toughness = inputs.t;
let save = inputs.sv <= 6 ? inputs.sv : 7;
```